# rails - kaminari pagination to non resource method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2, kaminari

kaminari is handeling pagination in my app, in example, if I want the missions index to be paginateable all I need is to add this code in `routes.rb`:

```
  concern :paginatable do
    get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''
  end

  resources :missions, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy], :concerns => :paginatable do
    post :done, on: :member
  end
```

and in the `missions_controller.rb`:

```
  def index
    missions = Mission.all
    if params[:page]
      missions = missions.page(params[:page])
    end
    respond_with missions
  end
```

but what if I have in `mission_controller.rb` another method - missions for user:

```
  def user
    missions = Mission.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
        if params[:page]
      missions = missions.page(params[:page])
    end
    respond_with missions
  end
```

in `routes.rb` it is configured like this:

```
  get 'users_missions' => 'missions#user'
```

how can I configure routes.rb to support pagination for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved by adding another row in routes.rb:

```
  get 'users_missions/page/:page' => 'missions#user'
```

next to the previous (`get 'users_missions' => 'missions#user'`)